# problem calibrating kinect ROS Fuerte

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to calibrate a Kinect following the steps of that tutorial:

openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration (I cannot type links)

All seems to run perfect, I can do the calibration, I can save it and commit it, but the problem appears when I see the path:

ls ~/.ros/camera_info/

It is suppose that I shuold see depth_****.yaml and rgb_****.yaml files, created by the calibration program, but I only have the RGB file! :( Do you know why only the RGB has been created? May I have to create the depth file manually? How? Can someone help me?

Thanx in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60944/problem-calibrating-kinect-ros-fuerte/) by [dalogi84](https://answers.ros.org/users/4691/dalogi84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Here's a procedure I always use...make sure you calibrate the RGB and IR cameras separately**

Kinect Calibration: RGB and IR Cameras

Packages Needed:

git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline.git

git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common.git

Install dependences: rosdep install ______

Make packages: rosmake ______

Procedure:

For RGB Camera

1.) roscore

2.) rosrun openni_camera openni_node

3.) rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.059 image:=/rgb/image_raw
rgb:=/rgb

Note: Size is number of rows of boxes-1 by number of columns of boxes-1.

Square is size of boxes in meters.

4.) Make sure Kinect is stationary. Move the checkerboard around slowly, changing the 6 degrees of
freedom: x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw.

5.) Keep changing the position of the checkerboard until the X, Y, Size, and Skew green bars on the right side
of the screen are at a maximum.

6.) When the “Calibrate” button is lit, click it.

7.) When the “Save” button is lit, click it.

8.) This saves a .tar file in your system’s ‘tmp’ folder. Find it and extract the files somewhere handy. Inside
the extracted folder will be pictures and a ost.txt file. Change the file extension to ost.ini and copy it to
your sandbox/workspace.

9.) rosrun camera_calibration_parsers convert ost.ini cal.yml

10.) This saves the cal.yml in your sandbox/workspace. Change the extension to .yaml. Also, change the file
name corresponding to what openni_node refrenced in the terminal when it was trying to find the calibration
file. It’s usually something like “RGB_A00366812242050A”. Once the file name is changed, open the file in a
text editor and change the default camera_name to “RGB_A00366812242050A”, or whatever name
openni_node refrenced.

11.) Now, copy this .yaml file to home/.ros/camera_info folder

Note: The .ros folder might be a hidden folder

For IR Camera

1.) Procedure is the same except:

a.) Cover the IR projector with tape/paper

b.) Make sure you are in a low light environment with incandescent or halogen lighting.
Fluorescent lighting interferes with the IR calibration. Also, make sure there is minimal
movement…the IR camera is very finicky.

c.) rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.059
image:=/ir/image_raw ir:=/ir

---

Originally posted by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) with karma: 108 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dalogi84](https://answers.ros.org/users/4691/dalogi84/) on 2013-04-21**:
Thanx very much! I found my error thanx to your explanation! :)

**Comment by [eskendertamrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/5193/eskendertamrat/) on 2013-09-18**:
@ ee.cornwell ... You're simply a life saver. I go through a lot of documents for the calibration of my kinect, but your instructions are as clear as anyone asks. Thanks. I ran into a problem in step 9, though

when I type ... rosrun camera_calibration_parsers convert ost.ini cal.yml

it gives me error msgs ... ERROR] [1379405204.741886123]: Unable to open camera calibration file [ost.ini]
[ERROR] [1379405204.741956956]: Failed to load camera model from file ost.ini

Do you have any idea as for how I could fix this? Thanks.

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-09-20**:
It sounds like the .ini file is either not in your current directory or you didn't change the file extention .txt to .ini.  That's the only thing I can think of...I've never came across this error.  Make sure you are sourcing the command window and you cd to the directory where the .ini file is saved in.